# Torus of revolution difeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

> Prove by means of the function $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $h(\theta, \varphi)=((2+ \cos \theta) \cos \varphi, (2+ \cos \theta) \sin \varphi, \sin \theta)$ that $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \mathbb{Z}^2$ is difeomorphic to the torus of revolution $\mathbb{T} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ obtained by rotating around the z axis the circle $C_0$ is in the xz plane, has radius 1 and center $ (2,0,0) $

It is easy to see that a parameter of the torus of revolution is  $((2+ \cos \theta) \cos \varphi, (2+ \cos \theta) \sin \varphi, \sin \theta)$, which is the same function $h$. How can I proceed to show the difeomorphism?

Comment: Your $\backslash$ would ordinarily be written as $/$. Can you start by proving homeomorphism (and then diffeo is a local check)?

Comment: It should be $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ rather than $\mathbb R^3/\mathbb Z^2$. .